If $\text{span}(\{A_i\}) = \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$, does $\sum_i A_i \otimes (A_i)^*$ have a unique maximal eigenvalue?
Suppose that I have a set of $n \times n$ complex matrices $\{A_i\}$, and suppose that this set spans the space of $n \times n$ matrices. Does $\sum_i A_i \otimes (A_i)^*$ have a unique maximal eigenvalue? By maximal, I mean in the sense of having the largest absolute value.

I am trying to better understand results using matrix product state descriptions of quantum states. Note that $\sum_i A_i \otimes (A_i)^*$ is a positive map and is guaranteed to have a positive real eigenvalue equal to its spectral radius; this follows from Norbert Schuch's answer to my question. If the answer to my question above is positive, this eigenvalue will be the only eigenvalue with modulus equal to the spectral radius.
Note that in my notation $A^*$ refers to the complex conjugate of $A$ and not the Hermitian conjugate of $A$.
